# Use Django if statement to run JavaScript on webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to show the image only if the output of the data comes out. So this JavaScript function should been executed only when `data` exists. Here is the code:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<title>
Python button script
</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if data %}
{{data | safe}}
{% endif %}
<form action="/external/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
Input Text:
<input type="text" name="param" required><br><br>


<p id="demo" style="color:red">{{data_external}} {{data1}}
</p>
 <img id="pic" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}" style="display:none;" />
<input type="submit" onclick="reloadimg();" value="Execute External Python Script">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    function reloadimg(){
        var src = "{% static 'images/graph.png' %}";
        imageObject = document.getElementById("pic");
        imageObject.style.display = 'inline-block';
        imageObject.src = src;
    }
</script>
```

How can I achieve such a result? If there is anything I needed to add to this question, just let me know.

Comment: Wrap your `img` tag in `{% if data %}` and `{% endif %}`?

Comment: Isn't that the desired behavior? If no data, no image. Or is your question really about why the data is empty/doesn't exit?